# Is the hierarchy of relative geometric constructibility by straightedge and compass a dense order?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, fields, geometric-constructions

Consider the hierarchy of relative geometric constructibility by
straightedge and compass. Namely, given a geometric figure $B$, a
set of points in the plane, we define that geometric figure $A$ is
*constructible from* $B$, written as $$A\leq B,$$ if from points in
$B$ using straightedge and compass we may construct every point in
$A$.

This is a partial preorder on geometric figures, considered as sets of
points in the Euclidean plane. The order gives rise to a
corresponding strict order notion $A<B$, which holds when from $B$
we may construct $A$ but not conversely. That is, $$A<B\qquad\text{
if and only if }\qquad A\leq B\quad\text{ and }\quad B\not\leq A.$$

**Question.** Is the hierarchy of relative geometric constructibility a
dense order? That is, if $A<B$ for figures in the plane, is there a figure $C$
such that $A<C<B$?

I would also be interested to know whether the answer depends on
considering only finite sets of points or infinite sets.

[**Update.** The main question is now answered by the maximality argument of Pace Nielsen below, but remains open in the case of finite figures. That is, if $A$ and $B$ are finite geometric figures with $A<B$, must there be some figure $C$ strictly between?]

Let me make a few observations. First, relative constructibility is symmetric on line segments. That is, if a line segment $AB$ is constructible from $CD$, then $CD$ is
constructible from $AB$. Thus, the relation of relative constructibility on line segments is an equivalence relation, with no occurences of the strict order. The argument is given on [my blog
post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/the-hierarchy-of-geometric-constructibility-can-we-go-back/).
For this reason, there will be no counterexamples to density using
segments only.

The symmetry claim is not true, however, for triangles. For
example, from a unit length and $\sqrt[3]{2}$, we can construct a
unit isosceles right triangle, but from such a triangle, we cannot
construct the length $\sqrt[3]{2}$. This instance is also discussed on my blog post.

Since this case has the feeling of being perhaps a minimal extension, it might be considered as a natural candidate counterexample, and several people (including David Madore and Nikolay Nikolov) have proposed various arguments that make definite progress. But the matter is currently still open.

A constructively closed set $S$ of points in the plane is
determined by any two of them and the set of points on the
corresponding line $\ell$. The reason is that if point $p\in S$,
then the distances between $p$ and two points on $S\cap\ell$ will
be a distance witnessed on $S\cap\ell$, and so we can construct $p$
via circles from points on $S\cap\ell$.

Therefore, a constructively closed set of points in the plane is
determined by a unit segment and the real field of distances
realized by that set. (one can also simply view the points as
complex numbers, as determined by a unit segment from the set.) For
this reason, the question is equivalent to the following:

**Question.** If $K< L$ are quadratically closed field
extensions of the rationals, must there be a quadratically closed
field $F$ strictly between them?
$$K< F< L$$
Such a field would correspond to a strictly intermediate set of points between $K$ and $L$ in the hierarchy of relative constructibility.

Regarding the natural candidate counterexample, the question would be: is there a quadratically closed field strictly between the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Comment: Incidentally, is there a notation for "the quadratic closure of"?

Comment: How about $F^{\sqrt{}}$?

Comment: The next natural candidate for a counterexample would be the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^3)$ and the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, with $\alpha$ a transcendental number. I thought that it was obvious that there is nothing between them, because it would mean that there is some element $\beta$ of degree $2^n$ which is expressible with $\alpha$ and $\alpha^3$ and square roots, but not with $\alpha^3$ alone, and then using the minimal polynomial of $\beta$, we would have a contradiction that $\alpha$ is transcendental, but I'm unable to conclude rigorously.

Comment: @QuinnLesquimau Good idea! If you are right, it would settle the density question for finite figures negatively.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Exactly. However, the interesting case of finite subsets with algebraic coordinates would still be open.

Comment: @QuinnLesquimau First, to make computations slightly cleaner, we can replace the base field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^3)$ with $F_0=\mathbb{Q}(\omega,\alpha^3)$, where $\omega$ is a cube-root of unity, since this is a quadratic extension.  Now, consider the field $K=F_0(\alpha,t_1=\sqrt{1+\alpha+\alpha^2},t_2=\sqrt{1+\omega \alpha+\omega^2 \alpha^2})$.  This is a Galois extension of $F_0$, since the only (seemingly) missing Galois conjugate is $t_3=\sqrt{1+\omega^2\alpha + \omega \alpha^2}=(\alpha^3-1)/(t_1t_2)$.  It should have order $12$ over $F_0$, and it should not contain any quadratic extension

Comment: ...of $F_0$, and hence $Gal(K/F_0)$ is $A_4$.  Then the argument in my post should apply.

Comment: Isn’t ≤ actually a preorder rather than a partial order? The point c = ½a + ½b is compass-and-straightedge constructible from { a, b }, but for a ≠ b, { a, b } and { a, b, c } are hardly *equal* sets, which means antisymmetry is not satisfied. (Also, { a, b, c } ≤ { a, b } looks a bit funny.) I am sure this can be addressed by constructing a suitable quotient, so this is pretty nitpicky, but still…

Comment: Yes, I should have said pre-order--now edited. My definition of the strict order is the one appropriate for pre-orders.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are three answers.  Throughout let $qcl(F)$ be the quadratic closure of a field $F$ inside $\mathbb{C}$.

**Part 1:**  Yes there is a quadratically closed field strictly between $qcl(\mathbb{Q})$ and $qcl(\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}))$.  First, find an $S_4$-extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$.  (My friend Darrin Doud tells me that the Galois closure of adjoining a root of $x^6 + 3x^4 + 3x^2 + 3$ will be such an $S_4$ extension.)  Note that $K$ is a subfield of $qcl(\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}))$, being constructible from $2^{1/3}$ by a sequence of square roots.

Now,  $K$ has a unique subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ quadratic over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Then $K/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ is an $A_4$-extension, and hence there exists a non-Galois subfield $F$ with $[F:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})]=4$.  Note, in particular, that the Galois closure of $F$ requires a degree $3$ extension.  We know that $F$ is not contained in $qcl(\mathbb{Q})$ because $qcl(\mathbb{Q})$ is Galois but contains no cubic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Also, $qcl(F)$ is proper in $qcl(\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}))$, since $qcl(F)$ is formed only using power-of-2 extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Part 2:**  The order is not dense.  Just use Zorn's lemma (or transfinite induction, if you want to avoid the axiom of choice) to construct a quadratically closed subfield of $qcl(\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}))$ that is maximal with respect to not containing $2^{1/3}$.

**Part 3:** If by "geometrical figure" you mean a *finite* set of points, then I don't know the answer to the first question anymore.  (Edited to add: I've now also answered this question in the negative.  I've put it as a separate answer.)

Comment: Excellent! The Zorn/maximality argument answers the density question very clearly. Meanwhile, as you mention, the density question for finite figures remains open.

Answer (score 10):

There are a lot of computations in this answer, so I hope there is no mistake. Answer to the small last question: there is a quadratically closed field strictly between the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. Let $K$ be the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, and $L$ be the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. The roots of the polynomial $P(x) := x^4 + 36x + 54$ are not in $K$, but they are in $L$, and $P$ is irreducible because it is irreducible modulo $5$, hence any root $\alpha$ of it is of degree $4$, and the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is strictly between $K$ and $L$. (I used https://www.alpertron.com.ar/POLFACT.HTM for the calculations modulo 5.)

First, why are the roots of $P$ not in $K$? It is because mod $7$, it decomposes in $(x+6)(x^3+x^2+x+2)$, which are irreducible, and the discriminant of this polynomial is $-5038848$, which is not divisible by $7$, therefore by Dedekind's theorem there is a cycle of order $3$ in the Galois group of $P$ (Again, calculation modulo 7 with https://www.alpertron.com.ar/POLFACT.HTM, and calculation of the discriminant with https://planetcalc.com/8188/.)

Finally, it is in the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, because we can look at the explicit formula for the roots of a quartic:

[image]

In our case, $a = b = 0$, therefore $e = \sqrt{(27c^2)^2-4(12d)^3} = 11664$, and $f = \sqrt[3]{27c^2 + e} = \sqrt[3]{2^6 \cdot 3^6} = 2^2 \cdot 3^2$. Except that, only square roots and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ appear in the formula, thus the roots are in $L$.

Answer (score 6):

I've figured out how to do the finite graph case, in the negative.  The ordering of quadratically closed fields is not dense in that case either.  Throughout let $qcl(F)$ denote the quadratic closure of $F$.

Let $\alpha$ be such that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ and there is no intermediate field.  (For instance, take any $S_4$ or $A_4$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and take a fixed field for any index $4$ subgroup.)  We know then that $qcl(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))$ properly contains $qcl(\mathbb{Q})$.  We will show there is no intermediate quadratically closed field.

Let $\beta\in qcl(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))$.  Let $K$ be the Galois closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.  Since $\beta$ can be captured by a sequence of quadratic extensions, we know that $K/\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is also created by a sequence of quadratic extensions, and in particular $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is a power of $2$.

Assume $qcl(\mathbb{Q}(\beta))\subsetneq qcl(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))$.  Then $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\beta)]=4$, since $\alpha$ is not constructible from $\beta$.  Therefore, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]=[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]$.  In particular, if $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, it remains irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.  Therefore, all the roots of $f$ lie in $K$. Hence, the Galois group of $f$ (i.e., the Galois closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$) is a $2$-group.  Therefore, $\beta\in qcl(\mathbb{Q})$.